# Female names containing "black" and "white"

Tags: names, english-to-japanese

What are the most common Japanese names with the word black and white?

According to google "white" = *shiro* and "black" = *kuro*.

For example white and black princess: *Shirohime*, *Kurohime*. I'm not sure though if these are valid names in Japanese.

I'm looking for names with meaning as I'm currently writing a non-fictional story.

Comment: This looks like a weird [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to me. Why do you need such names?

Comment: I'm currently trying to write a fictional story and I need female Japanese names stated above. Though google listed some names, I'm really not confident with them. If possible for someone from Japan to share such names, I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: >I'm currently trying to write a fictional story and I need female Japanese names stated above. At least, 白雪｛しらゆき｝ or *Shirayuki* could be used safely for the purpose.

Comment: you can look around on MAL for inspiration for actual fictional characters using those parts in the name

Answer (score 5):

You should distinguish

1. names that contain the reading しろ・しら or くろ, and
2. names that contain the *kanji* 白 or 黒.

---

Given the obvious associations with white ("clarity", "light", "brightness", etc.) and black, black is quite rare as a given name. As for the two points above,

1. As noted by @mackygoo, シロ or クロ are names often given to animals.

   Even the `#names` database on http://jisho.org/ (based on [ENAMDICT](http://www.edrdg.org/enamdict/enamdict_doc.html)) containing over 100,000 female given names, contains only very rare or unusual names containing しろ・しら with the meaning of "white" and even fewer containing くろ:

   > 白【しろ】、白雨【しろう】、白風【しろっぷ】、白羽【しらは】、白桐【しらぎり】、…
   >   黒乃【くろの】、黒子【くろこ】
2. There are a number of names containing the *kanji* 白, by writing a name like あきら、きよし、ゆき with the *kanji* 白. Essentially, 白 can stand  in for 清（きよ）、明（あき）、雪（ゆき）、… as well as having an addition reading of はく (or simply は by artistic license):

   > 白【あきら】、白【きよし】、白【ゆき】、…
   >   白華【きよか】、白胡【あきこ】、白江【きよえ】、…
   >   彩白【いろは】、…

   This second set contains more reasonable names that are loosely associated to "white", however the reading alone (say, Kiyoka) would not be enough to see this association (**白**華).

Answer (score 2):

Although 白 and 黒 are often used as it is as a name of a dog like シロ or クロ according to the color, there are not many cases used as a woman's name as it is or as a part, especially for 黒.
For 白 that may be used, "雪{ゆき} *snow*" or "鶴{つる} *crane*" which is reminiscent of 白 is often used as it is or as part of the name. I'll show you relatively common names examined [here](http://name.m3q.jp/list?s=%E9%9B%AA&g=2) and [here](http://name.m3q.jp/list?g=2&s=%E9%B6%B4).

- 鶴:
  つる, 鶴{つる}, 千鶴｛ちづる｝, 千鶴子｛ちづこ｝, 田鶴子｛たづこ｝, 鶴代｛つるよ｝, ...
- 雪:
  ゆき, 雪{ゆき, せつ}, 雪子{ゆきこ, せつこ}, 小雪{こゆき}, 雪愛{ゆきな}, 雪愛{ゆきな}, 雪乃{ゆきの}, 白雪｛しらゆき, はゆ｝, ...

By the way, 白雪姫{しらゆきひめ} for *Snow White* in "Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs" is very famous in Japan.

白雪{しらゆき} could be as a female name and it sounds beautifully, but I've never heard it as an actual name.